# npm start not working in the react app, what do i do?

Tags: reactjs

So i created a react app when and I did npm start for the first time, the app opened in the browser, no issues. Subsequently I closed the tab & the VSC editor. Now that i try "npm start" again in the VSC terminal, the app doesnt open and I get a strange response.
This is my first proper question on Stackoverflow and first project on React please be kind to me.

After making the app using create-react-app my-app and doing npm start and the project running well. Now when i do npm start this happens:

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Coding\React\Practice> npm start

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path 

C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Coding\React\Practice/package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Coding\React\Practice\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent
```

Except npm help, no other command runs. Please help me out.

Comment: `no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Coding\React\Practice\package.json'`

Comment: First, you read the error message and then change your working directory in the CMD to the directory where your `package.json` is located ...

Comment: thank you @derpirscher my error is resolved. I just didn't know that the npm directory and the parent folder are dealt differently by changing the working directory. I am a self-taught developer and I keep discovering things like these. Thanks to the community and people like you for the prompt responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### npx create-react-app practice-app

#### cd practice-app

#### /practice-app/ npm start

You have to be inside the react application you have created to launch the application with npm or yarn. I think you were still on the parent folder which in this case is the Practice folder.

On vscode terminal type cd then press the tab button u will see all the folders contained inside the Practice folder coming up. keep pressing till your react project folder comes to the screen and press enter.

Then type code . to open the folder on vscode ide. Then use npm start or yarn start on the project to start.

Comment: Thank you, brother. I am a self-taught developer learning things one by one. because the create-react-app had happened in the parent (practice) folder I assumed all npm commands are run there, now I know the working directory has to be changed, Thank you :)

Comment: it is not a problem follow codewithharry youtube channel. Best resources are there for a self taught develper try him out

Comment: sure bro. i followed harry for HTML and CSS and was referring to another channel for React. will look up harry also.